# 'TypeErroe: cannot read property NAME of undefined' after trying to retrieve key/ value from nested object

Tags: react-native, object, async-await, fetch, state

I am trying to fetch some data in `react-native` where I store the fetched data in a `state` variable so I can access them anywhere in the component. This is the code:

```
export default class Result extends Component {
    state = {
        data: {}
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const that = this;
        const url = 'https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/8002270014901.json';
        let response = await fetch(url);
        if (response.status == 200) {
            let data = await response.json();
            this.setState({ data });
        }
    }

    ... some code ...

    render() {
      console.log(this.state.data.product);

    ...some more code ...
    }
}
```

I got the code from the `componentDidMount` from another SOF article to make sure that I have some `data` I can work with.
When I try to test the outcome it works perfectly fine with the `console.log` you see in the code. But if I try to go just one layer deeper within the object (e.g. `console.log(this.state.data.product.brands);` I get the error message mentioned in the subject. Why is that? How do I make sure that the entire object is 'loaded' before I proceed?

Comment: Show the data structure , of this.state.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes to my mind in this case is that you are receiving the response after the `render` method is being executed.

You may ask *But how it works when I log just `this.state.data.product`?*
Well, when you initialize your state you are defining that it have a `data` object, so in that case the code won't break because `this.state.data.product` is `undefined`, but when you try to get one layer deeper now you are trying to access to a property of an `undefined` value, which leads to the error you are getting (cannot read property *x* of undefined).

### So, what can I make to fix that?

You have to store a boolean variable in your state, let's call it `fetchingData` and give it a default value of `true`, so now you have

```
state = {
  data: {},
  fetchingData: true
};
```

then, on your `render` method you validate if its fetching the data or if you already have te response from the server, modify it to be like this:

```
render() {
  if(this.state.fetchingData) return <View><Text>Fetching data...</Text></View>
  console.log(this.state.data.product.brands);
  return(
    Whatever you want to do with the data...
  )
}
```

What it does is when you are still waiting for the data, a `Fetching data...` message will be shown, now when you receive the data you also have to change `fetchingData` to false.

```
if (response.status == 200) {
  let data = await response.json();
  this.setState({
    data: data,
    fetchingData: false
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jose Vf. Very helpful comment!